# GROUP BY repeating result

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I can't use `GROUP BY` properly here, why `GROUP BY` is not fetching expected result.

I can't handle the join between table `fee` and `fee_tm`. While assigning `GROUP BY` to one, one will be fine but another one's row fetched according previous table's total rows(which id has been grouped). I'd tried assigning `group_by` to both, but output is both row doubled.

**Expected output**

[image]

**Real Result**

But here row is repeated accordingly `fee_tm.id` total rows, then output is fetched as

[image]

**Structure of Database**

**fee_tm**

```
id  |   ttl |   year
=====================
1   |   Jan |   1
2   |   Feb |   1
3   |   Mar |   1
```

**fee**

```
id  |   ttl     |   year
========================
1   |   Annual  |   1
2   |   Monthly |   1
```

**cls_fee**

```
id  |   cls_id  |   sec_id  |   fee_id |    fee
================================================
1   |   1       |   1       |   1      |    1000
2   |   1       |   1       |   2      |    560
```

**student**

```
id  |   ttl |   cls |   sec |   year
====================================
1   |   John|   1   |   1   |   1
2   |   Riya|   1   |   1   |   1
```

MYSQL

```
$result=$con->prepare("
    SELECT
        fee_tm.ttl AS f_tm,
        cls_fee.fee AS f_mnt,
        fee.ttl AS f_ttl
    FROM
        student
    LEFT JOIN
        fee_tm ON fee_tm.year = student.year
    JOIN
        cls_fee ON cls_fee.sec_id = student.sec AND cls_fee.cls_id = student.cls
    LEFT JOIN
        fee ON fee.id = cls_fee.fee_id
    WHERE
        student.id =:stdt
    GROUP BY
        fee_tm.id";

    $results=array();
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[]=$row;
        echo"
        <input type='checkbox' name='f_id' /'>".$row['f_tm'];
    } echo "<br/>
    <table>";

    foreach($results as $row1){
        echo"
        <tr>
            <td>".$row1['f_ttl']."</td>
            <td>".$row1['f_mnt']."</td>
        </tr>";
} echo "</table>";
```

Result of `print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [fee] => Feb [f_mnt] => 1000 [f_ttl] => Annual Fee ) 
[1] => Array ( [fee] => Mar [f_mnt] => 1000 [f_ttl] => Annual Fee ) 
)
```

Comment: @user3783243, you mean I am looping twice

Comment: Yes, but might not be the way I initially read it.  Does `$result` come back with the duplicate rows?

Comment: @user3783243, no I am just storing in array for further use

Comment: @AnandHmt first just printout your raw query results, and see if there are on expected lines or not.

Comment: There is no `sec_fee` table in your question, other than in the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry what do you mean. My expected result is in question.

Comment: Include your expected _MySQL_ result in your question please.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, typing mistake, It have to be `cls_fee` and in my text editor it is `cls_fee`. While typing here, typo mistake, just edited

Comment: What does `print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` give back?

Comment: @user3783243, I've updated question with result of  `print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, please see